# Python-Webscrape Linkedin Listing

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

The url in the code directs to a number of listings on LinkedIn

I just want to get the link/href of each listing, but the output produces blank. I just want html of every listing.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'}
url='https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=2213597199&geoId=103644278&keywords=cyber%20analyst&location=United%20States&start=25'
r=requests.get(url,headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
listing=soup.find_all('div',class_="job-card-container relative job-card-list job-card-container--clickable job-card-list--underline-title-on-hover jobs-search-results-list__list-item--active jobs-search-two-pane__job-card-container--viewport-tracking-1")
for info in listing:
    link= info.find('a',href=True)
    print(link)
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this with `requests`, there's too much client side rendering. You'll have to switch to a headless browser (perhaps chrome), and use selenium. Also get ready for requests being denied - those guys don't like when they are being scraped.

Comment: requests has not been denied, it is do-able..

Comment: yes, request is not denied, but you aren't getting the actual data you want, you're only getting html part, the info about listing themselves is loaded through JavaScript. And `requests` won't be executing javascript. Try this - get the blob of the text, and try searching for words you're trying to scrape - they won't be there.

Comment: You are right :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you might want to give `selenium` a shot.

Here's how to get all job offer follow links:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=2213597199&geoId=103644278&keywords=cyber%20analyst&location=United%20States&start=0&redirect=false"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-card__full-card-link")
job_links = [e.get_attribute("href") for e in elements]

for job_link in job_links:
    print(job_link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/cyber-threat-intelligence-analyst-at-linkedin-2261917520?refId=b5cf1ce3-d032-4aaa-8810-26d4782cc34d&position=1&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/cyber-security-analyst-at-modis-2273028250?refId=b5cf1ce3-d032-4aaa-8810-26d4782cc34d&position=2&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/jr-python-cyber-analyst-ts-sci-at-deloitte-2265989857?refId=b5cf1ce3-d032-4aaa-8810-26d4782cc34d&position=3&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/cyber-security-analyst-at-modis-2307968344?refId=b5cf1ce3-d032-4aaa-8810-26d4782cc34d&position=4&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/entry-level-cyber-security-analyst-at-hcl-technologies-2271846580?refId=b5cf1ce3-d032-4aaa-8810-26d4782cc34d&position=5&pageNum=0&trk=public_jobs_job-result-card_result-card_full-click
and so on ..
```

The class you're after is here:

[image]

Comment: Hi, the code runs. Can you attach a screen shot of class (result-card__full-card-link)

I found this before but cant locate it even tho the code runs